# Array with paths showing on a single line

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm stuck!
I feel like I've tried everything and googled forever. No matter what I do; when I try to list arrays containing paths they all show up without line breaks. Even when I try to use a split command I can't get one item per line when listing the array.
Here's some parts of the code in question ...

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$24fps = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$30fps = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$48fps = @()

$video = ".\*.mov"

Get-ChildItem $video -recurse | ForEach-Object {

   $ffprobeFPSData = ffprobe -select_streams V:0 -v 0 -of csv=p=0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate $_ | Out-String
   $FPSVariables = $ffprobeFPSData -replace "`n" -replace "" -split '/'
   $averageFPS = [decimal]$FPSVariables[0]/$FPSVariables[1]

   Write-Host "$($_.BaseName)$($_.Extension) - FPS: $($averageFPS)"

   if ([int]$averageFPS -le 26) {
      [array]$24fps.Add($_.FullName)
      $CFRValue = 24
   }
   elseif ([int]$averageFPS -le 35) {
      [array]$30fps.Add($_.FullName)
      $CFRValue = 30
   }
   else {
      [array]$48fps.Add($_.FullName)
      $CFRValue = 48
   }
}

Write-Host "24 FPS: $($24fps)`n"
Write-Host "30 FPS: $($30fps)`n"
Write-Host "48 FPS: $($48fps)`n"
```

I have tried splitting it like so:
With this I can get single entries, but I still haven't figured out a way to list them all. It makes me think there is something wrong with the way I have made the array, but I can't figure out in what way ,,,

```
$test = $30fps -split ' D:'

Write-Host "TEST ARRAY `"$($test[3])`"`n"
Write-Host "TEST ARRAY `"$($test[45])`"`n"
```

Comment: Try ```$test = $30fps -join "`n"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `Write-Host` behavior is to  join the array elements using a space as a separator instead of a new line.

Therefore, by itself, it is not a good fit.

There are various way to do what you want though.

`Out-Host`

```
$30fps | Out-Host
```

Sometimes you might really want to use Write-Host to add some custom colors, in which case, you can pipe the array through `Out-String` first, then to `Write-Host`

```
$30fps | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

Or you might want to iterate through the elements to add something arbitrary for display purposes, such as an index, in which case a `ForEach` would do the trick

```
$index = 0 
$30FPS | Foreach {Write-Host "$("$($index).".PadRight(10,' '))$_";$index+=1}
```

Finally, closest to what you wrote is a single line `Write-Host` but we combine the array elements into a multiline string first.

```
Write-host "$($30fps  -join "`n")"
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! So it seems like the only problem was that I tried to print the array using Write-Host?

Comment: @ErikErik `Write-Host` need to determine what to do when you pass it something that is not a string. In the case of an array, the choice made internally is to do `$Arr -join ' '` and print that. That's why you get your array elements on the same line separated by spaces only. Therefore you can't just pass it an array. All the snippets I added are to deal with that fact.  Another way to deal with an array:   `Write-host "$($30fps  -join "`n")"`